# Bootstrap 4: how to center a card

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am building a school website template using Bootstrap 4.

I use a card to make the staff page. But I can't center the card.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="card text-center" style="width: 21.5em;">
   <img class="card-img-top" src="images/placeholder.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
   <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Center, where? which way? where is the corresponding code?

Answer (score 1):

You Can Use :

```
style="width: 21.5em;margin:0 auto;"
```

your card will be centered.